# Decide if the series converges by using comparison test: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n^{2}+n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> Decide if the series converges by using comparison test:
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n^{2}+n}$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n^{2}+n}>\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n}{n^{2}}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$

Thus the series diverges because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Did I do it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To lower bound a fraction, you can remove positive term from the numerator (which you did and is correct) but you cannot remove positive term from the denominator ! I would suggest the following bound :
$$
\frac{2n+1}{n^2 + n} > \frac{2n}{n^2 + n^2} = \frac{1}{n}$$

Then your conclusion about the harmonic series is correct.

---

EDIT : Some more information bounds for fraction :
To lower bound a fraction you either have to lower bound the top or upper bound the bottom, or both. In our case we have :
$$
2n + 1 > 2n \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(lower bound of the top)} \\
n^2 + n < n^2 + n^2 \ \ \ \ \ \text{(upper bound of the bottom)}
$$
(For upper bounding it the opposite : upper bound the top or lower bound the bottom or both)

Comment: So to sum up: It is allowed to add / remove something in the numerator. It is allowed to add something in the denumerator but it's not allowed to remove something in the denumerator? Can I write it down like that in my notes?

Comment: @cnmesr Almost. The fraction gets smaller if either the numerator decreases, or the denominator increases. So you can remove something in the numerator, or add something in the denominator.

Comment: To lower bound a fraction you can : remove positive term from the top or add negative term to the top or add positive term to the bottom or remove negative term from the bottom.
You can do all of these separately or at the same time.

Comment: Last question, what am I allowed to do to upper bound a fraction?

Comment: Thanks a lot by the way, forgot to say!

Comment: Exactly the inverse !
To upper bound a fraction : add positive term to the top, remove negative term from the top, add negative term to the bottom, remove positive term from the bottom.

Comment: ISSOU LA CHANCLA :hap:

Answer (score 2):

One other way to see it is to notice that

$${2n+1\over n^2+n}={n+1\over n^2+n}+{n\over n^2+n}={1\over n}+{1\over n+1}$$

And we're done

Comment: Thank you! For me I think your way is much easier to do than other ways.

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}>\frac{2n}{n^2}$ is equivalent with $2n^3+n^2>2n^3+2n^2$, which is equivalent with $n^2<0$, which doesn't hold. Your approach is wrong.